# Javascript validation and posting at the same time

Tags: javascript

```
function echeck(str) {

    var at="@"
    var dot="."
    var lat=str.indexOf(at)
    var lstr=str.length
    var ldot=str.indexOf(dot)
    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1){
       alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr){
       alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(dot)==-1 || str.indexOf(dot)==0 || str.indexOf(dot)==lstr){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
    }

     if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     return true                    
}
```

function ValidateForm(){
    var emailID=document.frmSample.txtEmail

```
if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
    alert("Please Enter your Email ID")
    emailID.focus()
    return false
}
if (echeck(emailID.value)==false){
    emailID.value=""
    emailID.focus()
    return false
}
return true
```

}

Enter an Email Address :

I'm using the following script but I cant figure out how to post the form to another php script where I'm trying to email the inputted addresses?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, you may want to look into using [regular expressions](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml) to validate that email address as opposed to manually looking for specific characters in the string.  The code will be more succinct and the expression will capture a wider variety of incorrect entries.  You can find a variety of expressions that capture email addresses by doing a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `action` attribute in your form?

```
<form action="myScript.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" action="another.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (echeck(str)) {
    submitForm() //or use document.getElementById("formId").submit()
}
```